# Download a specified number of files from every subfolder in an S3 bucket?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

**Context:** Say I have an S3 Bucket structured like this:

```
Top Level Prefix
    Sub Prefix A
        Objects 1...100+
    Sub Prefix B
        Objects 1...100+
```

**Note:** I will never have a situation where Objects are alongside prefixes in a subfolder. For example a structure like this will not occur:

```
Top Level Prefix
    Objects 1...100+
    Sub Prefix A
        Objects 1...100+
    etc.
```

**Goal:** I would like to download a specified number of files "N" from each subfolder.

**Attempted Solution/Algorithm:**

1. I would use `boto3`'s `list_objects_v2` Delimited to `'/'` to get a list of common prefixes into a list.
2. I would then use `list_objects_v2` once again on the Bucket but this time fill the `Prefix` parameter with elements from the list we constructed in the prior step (via a loop). I would also set the `MaxKeys` parameter to the value "N" specified earlier.
3. On each iteration of the loop, I would append the returned keynames to another list (which should end up being length N)
4. Lastly, I would iterate over that list of keynames and download them using `boto3`'s `.download_file()` method.

**Question:** How would I do this? I found this code which gets the top level folder/prefix names, but it doesn't find subfolders:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=bucket_region)

def list_folders(s3_client, bucket_name):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix='', Delimiter='/')
    print(response)
    for content in response.get('CommonPrefixes', []):
        yield content.get('Prefix')
```

Comment: The `list_objects_v2()` command will provide a list of `CommonPrefixes` for the specified Prefix. Since you specified `Prefix=''`, it will only return `CommonPrefixes` that are in the _root_ of the bucket. If you wish to find 'subfolders', then you would need to call `list_objects_v2()` _again_ with `Prefix=` to one of the earlier CommonPrefixes returned. To put it in traditional language, it only shows one level of folders. To list subfolders, you will need to list each subfolder.

Comment: An alternate approach to your method would be to only list objects _once_ and use logic within your Python script to determine whether a new prefix was found. This way, it is only traversing the list _once_, rather than having to recurse into subdirectories. I would also recommend using an `s3_resource` (`for object in s3_resource.Bucket('foo').objects.all():`) to list the objects since it will automatically handle pagination where there are more than 1000 objects.

Comment: Does pagination occur before or after prefixing? I.e. If I pass a prefix to the list objects function, will it perform prefixing on a set of 1,000 objects or will no more than 1000 objects that satisfy the prefix be returned/searched? The reason I'm shying away from listing all the objects once is my bucket is massive. If I limit the search to begin with, it's much more manageable.

Comment: Mmm. I'd say the limit relates to the number of objects returned, not the number of objects 'scanned' to create the `CommonPrefixes`. So, your listing of 'directories' should be fine.

Comment: Okay. To simplify this question, is it even possible for me to just get a list of all subfolders (those folders that are the last folders before the actual data) in a bucket? I'm thinking of doing a kind of breadth first search on the prefixes but idk if that's actually possible.

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure of my above comment. The documentation says that `CommonPrefixes` is _"All of the keys (up to 1,000) rolled up into a common prefix count as a single return when calculating the number of returns."_ I recommend that you perform some tests to confirm whether all CommonPrefixes are returned in a single call.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein [The documentation does cover this ...  barely](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html), "All of the keys (up to 1,000) rolled up into a common prefix count as a single return when calculating the number of returns.".  In other words "Count of Contents" + "Count of CommonPrefixes" <= "Max Keys", and "Max Keys" will default to and max out at 1000.